# Akka log-dead-letters and log-dead-letters-during-shutdown don't work

Tags: scala, akka, dead-letter

This is a simple question, but it keeps bothering me and my logs.

I have a config:

```
akka {
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
  log-dead-letters = off
}
```

My program ends with `akkaSystem.terminate()`

I'm pretty sure that config is loaded to the system. I've tried different combinations with `false` or `0` instead of `off`. Nothing helps and my logs are getting filled with dead letters when the scheduled worker stops every 10 minutes.

This works in both dev and prod environments.

Comment: That's weird. How do you know the config is loaded?

Comment: Wait... My main actorsystem works just fine. Looks like reactivemongo uses its own configuration loaded from somewhere unknown.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was not about my own actor system, it was about reactive mongo which MongoDriver is using its own actor system and its own config.

(I am using mongo for persistence)

It must be like this:

```
mongo-async-driver {
  akka {
    log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
    log-dead-letters = 0
  }
}
```